# Magento how to define layout handle for all controller

Tags: magento, layout

Im looking for solution to define layout handle for whole controller insteat of controller_action. For example i want to define:

```
<mymodule_index></mymodule_index>
```

instead of

```
<mymodule_index_index></mymodule_index_index>
<mymodule_index_someaction></mumodule_index_someaction>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Good questions Styopchik

Comment: just trying to work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found solution. In each next update you must provide `<update handle="" />` like this:

```
<companies_catalog>
    <label>Companies (All Pages)</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="businesscategory/companies_navigation" name="companies.navigation" before="-" template="businesscategory/companies/navigation.phtml" />
    </reference>
</companies_catalog>

<companies_catalog_index>
    <label>Companies (All Pages)</label>
    <update handle="companies_catalog" />
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="businesscategory/companies_list" name="companies.list" template="businesscategory/companies/list.phtml" />
    </reference>
</companies_catalog_index>

<companies_catalog_view>
    <label>Company page</label>
    <update handle="companies_catalog" />
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="businesscategory/companies_view" name="company.info" template="businesscategory/companies/view.phtml" />
    </reference>
</companies_catalog_view>
```

Comment: In this case, you would still *have* to define one layout for each action. The solution I gave you would allow you to keep one layout handle for every action, and only override the actions you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a layout handle by running this :

`$update = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate();
 $update->addHandle('mymodule_index')`

You can then add this piece of code to a protected "_initHandles" function within your controller that you would run for every action.

Comment: Ok, i did as you wrote. When i dump layout updates, i get 
"companes_index". But, when i add layout update for <companiex_index> - it doesn't make any changes to my page. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you run `$this->loadLayoutUpdates();` before you render the layout ?

Comment: Yes, and have no success.

Comment: I would like to vote this up, but it is simply lacking too many crucial details.

Answer (score 1):

In my controller I've (re)implemented this method

```
public function loadLayout($handles = null, $generateBlocks = true, $generateXml = true)
    {
        return parent::loadLayout(array('default','mymodule_index'),$generateBlocks,$generateXml);
    }
```

which will add an update handle called mymodule_index (not loosing the default one) for every controller's action.
You'll need to call loadLayout() in every controller's action, but that's how magento works...

Comment: I'd vote for this solution anyday!  It's one instance of code that then applies across the board as desired.  I eliminates inserting redundant lines elsewhere in your code.

For clarity, you then need to add in your xml a handle `<mymodule_index>` - the XML definition this is referencing.

Answer (score 0):

please try below code....

```
 public function indexAction(){
    {
    ... 
    $update = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate();
     $update->addHandle('mymodule_index');
     $this->loadLayoutUpdates();
     $this->generateLayoutXml()->generateLayoutBlocks();
     $this->renderLayout();

    }
    public function samelocationAction(){
    {
    ... 
    $update = $this->getLayout()->getUpdate();
     $update->addHandle('mymodule_index');
     $this->loadLayoutUpdates();
     $this->generateLayoutXml()->generateLayoutBlocks();
     $this->renderLayout();

    }
```